# Setting Label text in swift

Tags: macos, swift, nstextfield

My first question here. I'm making the jump from Delphi and Pascal to Xcode and Swift and feeling totally overwhelmed by the change.

I'm simply attempting to change the text of a label when a button is clicked. Here is my code from ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Label1: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ChangeText: NSTextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    Label1.stringValue = "Hello World"
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

When I run the application as soon as I click the `button` the application hangs.

I've also tried exchanging `stringValue` with text but `NSTextField` does not use this. I can't seem to make the label show up as `UITextField`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should name your vars and functions starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: `... as soon as I click the button the application hangs` What does that mean? Is an exception thrown? Is it a bad signal that's terminating the app? Is it just pausing in the debugger because you have accidentally set a breakpoint? You need to be much more precise.

Comment: Is the button action linked to the correct implementation? (Right click the button in IB and see whether the action selector is *exactly* the same (case sensitive)). If not delete the action in IB and reconnect it.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. It is my first Mac OS app and my first time using swift and Xcode so thanks for the patience.

Comment: I had an accidentally set a break point like the noob I am.